# What is the difference between these two attiny44a parts?

Tags: identification, atmel, attiny

I bought two Chirp plant watering alarms and I noticed that the attiny44a used are marked differently: atmel1722 and atmel1619.

What is the meaning of the numbers? I cannot find this information in the datasheet.

Are they some sort of serial number or batch?

[image]

Comment: [Yep.](https://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/Data/GBNG-15KQFZ896/pcn_gbng-15kqfz896_part%20marking%20guideline_part1.pdf)

Comment: Also, note that the silkscreens on both boards are different, too. Not only in the font they use! One says `v.1.1`, the other `V1.1`. Someone took the board layout, and modified it slightly, and then made new gerbers, but they didn't change the version string – bad idea (don't do something that's different but has the same version and name - otherwise, versioning makes no sense).

Comment: @MarcusMüller come on, it's made in China copying a design from someone else :) I could have shown you the bottom part of the one on the left, where the opposite arrow overlaps the text! But they work fine and they cost less than 3 dollars, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are [date codes](https://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/Data/GBNG-15KQFZ896/pcn_gbng-15kqfz896_part%20marking%20guideline_part1.pdf): They represent the 22nd week of 2017 and 19th week of 2016, respectively.

*(Thanks to [Maple](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/187920/maple) for the link.)*